# Improve performance of the R program using Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm trying to speed up my R code - I'm wondering if this is something that can be done in Rcpp. This is my code that I started to write.

```r
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction('int cont.run_C(int reps=10000,int n=10000,int d=0.005,int l=10 ,int s=0.1) {
  r = rep(0, reps)
  theta = rep(0, n)
  for(int t = 0; t < reps; t++) {
    epsilon = rnorm(1, 0, d)
    Zt = sum(epsilon > theta ? 1 : epsilon < -theta ? -1: 0)
    r[t] = Zt / (l * n)
    theta = runif(n) < s ? abs(r[t]) : theta
  }
  return mean(r)
}')

system.time(cont.run_C())
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need a general background & intro to writing C++ code for use in the R statistical computing environment. I'd start w/ [Hadley's chapter on Rcpp](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html), then read through (at least) Rcpp's Introduction Vignette & Quick Reference, available [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html). Stack Overflow isn't really a service for free code writing/translation, but once you get a real start on this after doing basic background research, it *is* a great place to get help if you're stuck w/ a specific problem.

Comment: Yeah I'd check out some of the resources available. First at the end of each statement you need a semicolon. Additionally, you have to declare every variable before you use it (e.g. Zt is not declared). Also you need to make sure your types are correct (0.1 is a double not an integer )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before trying to translate your code to C++ it makes sense to look at the R code first, especially if you do not know C++. If you use a profiler on your code, you will see that much of the time is spent in the two lines with `ifelse`. However, both lines can be improved. The first line is equivalent to:

```
Zt <- sum(epsilon > theta) - sum(epsilon < -theta)
```

The second line can be written as

```
theta[runif(n) < s] <- abs(r[t])
```

These two changes reduce the runtime on my system from over 10s to under 5s. Looking at the profiler results again, we see that now most of the time is spent in `runif`. Here we can use a faster RNG from my [dqrng](https://www.daqana.org/dqrng/) package, reducing the runtime to under 2s. Final code:

```r
library(dqrng)

cont.run <- function(reps=10000, n=10000, d=0.005, l=10 ,s=0.1) {
  r <- rep(0, reps)
  theta <- rep(0, n)
  for (t in 1:reps) {
    epsilon <- dqrnorm(1, 0, d)
    #Zt = sum(ifelse(epsilon > theta, 1, ifelse(epsilon < -theta, -1, 0)))
    Zt <- sum(epsilon > theta) - sum(epsilon < -theta)
    r[t] <- Zt / (l * n)
    theta[dqrunif(n) < s] <- abs(r[t])
  }
  return(mean(r))
}

system.time(cont.run())
#>        User      System verstrichen 
#>       1.804       0.244       2.049
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for that - it is indeed better way to start with, and already improved the functionality of the code.